# Unable to unlock Apple Account

Tags: icloud, apple-id, accounts

So recently I have been facing an issue where I cannot unlock my apple ID.

Here how my process goes:

1. Login to my apple ID/icloud from either web or my MBA
2. I enter the username and password.
3. I get a message saying I need to unlock my account
4. Visit iforgot.apple.com to reset password/unlock account
5. Enter email
6. Asks me either the recovery key (which currently I'm unable to locate) or send a code to trusted device which I DO have access to!
7. I have it send a code to a trusted device
8. Enter CODE
9. Asks me for my current password
10. Here where things gets tricky, It tells me my password is incorrect.

I know my password is correct because it wouldn't have prompted me to unlock account. I know this because I learned through trial and error that when you enter wrong password, it says "incorrect password" for step 3.

I have been stuck in this loop for more than 2 weeks now since I returned back from my international trip.

Apple support keeps giving me the run around.

I use lastpass to manage passwords so I know my passwords are correct.

What can I do to recover my account?

Comment: What happens if you try to log in on https://appleid.apple.com/? And what exactly did Apple Support tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Without your recovery key - you're in a precarious state.

Apple lays out the steps to regenerate that from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202649

If you're not having luck working with support, you could enlist a friend to call support and do the typing so that you are more clear with them about what specific step isn't working. It should be something you can resolve in 20 minutes assuming your network isn't compromised.

Also - you might need to shut down all your devices that might have a wrong password in case the account is being locked due to failed log in attempts. Keep in mind - Apple is trained to be suspicious of requests to unlock an account from a different country since you've enabled enhances security of two step authentication on your account.

Comment: I dont have another other apple device.

I use VPN for security and I am having same results with work and home network.