# iCloud restore "Enter Old Passcode"

Tags: icloud, backup, restore

An iPhone 6 Plus' Touch ID stopped working and the user couldn't remember the passcode and, after many failed attempts, was forced to choose between setting up as a new iPhone or restoring from backup.

The iPhone 6 Plus was frequently backed up by iCloud and never backed up by iTunes.

Directly (from the initial setup) or indirectly (once setup as a new iPhone), attempting to restore from iCloud  prompted for and accepted Apple ID authentication (username, password, and phone number-based TFA) then prompted as follows and rejected all given:

> Enter Old Passcode
>
> Passwords, home and other data are protected by the passcode
>   previously used to unlock this iPhone.
>
> Your passcode is encrypted and cannot be read by Apple.

I wasn't able to find anything online regarding this scenario, hence this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Apple's technical support who said:

> At this point then we won’t be able to get past the passcode unless you manage to remember it at a later point in time
>
> The only way around this would be use the phone as new, and then sync with iCloud contacts, calendar and Photo library if you use those.

Personally, I have restored from iCloud and I was never prompted for my passcode so I guessed that it was prompting from a verification point-of-view, rather than an encryption point-of-view.

On an iPad, I enabled iCloud and signed in using the same Apple ID.

On the iPhone, restoring from iCloud prompted for a verification code from the iPad and succeeded.

Apple's technical support said:

> Oh perfect, you should be working here, haha

Comment: Nice solution - I wonder if this could help answer another question here by user Phoenix? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291055/got-a-new-iphone-where-am-i-supposed-to-receive-the-verification-code

Answer (score 1):

Where I work my employer requires iPhone passcodes to be changed every 90 days, which introduced a good bit of ambiguity as to what "old passcode" means (I have had this phone for about a year so the passcode changed many times).

The prompt says (emphasis mine):

> Passwords, home and other data are protected by the passcode **previously used to unlock this iPhone.**

Unfortunately, that bolded part was not entirely accurate in my case.

The way the prompt was written I at first thought the phone was asking for the passcode I used *previous* to my current passcode (i.e., the one from 90 days ago).

But to my surprise, my iPhone 6s (iOS 11) wanted the **original** passcode my phone was set up with when I first got it, **NOT** the up to date passcode I last used on the phone, or the one before it.

So hopefully if/when you get into [a situation](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5246208) where you need to sign in and out of your account you remember this (possibly ancient) passcode, keep it somewhere safe.