# How to approve iPhone if you have no other device?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, setup

After upgrading to latest iOS I get a message asking to approve my phone from another device.

Problem 1: **I do not** have another device. Is apple forcing customers to have more than one device? or how do i fix this?

Problem 2: It also gives me a message, "Can't approve this iPhone". If I click there it warns you that the only way to continue will be by resetting all my info on iCloud which is something I DO NOT WANT to do.

Comment: Do you have access to a computer that you can log into your iCloud account with? Another phone number? That is basically what they are asking for.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but this answer may resolve your issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291055/got-a-new-iphone-where-am-i-supposed-to-receive-the-verification-code

Comment: The other answer did not resolve my issue. But I was eventually able to fix it by logging into iCloud on an old laptop that my wife had, and approving the request from there.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  I actually had an old ipod associated with my account that I didn't realize and had to remove it.
Go to: https://appleid.apple.com
And choose "Manage your Account".
Look at your devices and see if you  have any old devices.  If so, remove them.  That is what worked for me.

Comment: upvoted, relevant to problem 1. I think the message to approve a login from another device only appears if there is a device associated with your AppleID.  You can see all the devices you've ever used by going to the above website, and remove them if you don't own/use them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I just sorted this issue out on my phone with somebody from Apple customer service.

All you have to do is to go to the bottom of the page where it says something like: "Can't approve this iphone?", click on this option and you will have to reset your encrypted data. Don't worry because you will lose nothing. This encrypted data is connected to your Keychain option in your iphone which stores your passwords you use to automatically loggin into different apps. You will just be asked to re-loggin, if this will be the case, when you will use an app for which you've saved the loggin password.
Once you followed all steps in resetting your encrypted data you will be redirected back to the original screen and you will have to click again on "Continue", enter again your password for your Apple ID account and this should be all. Your phone should work and it will be approved.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There should be the option to receive a SMS code instead (if you have a phone linked to your Apple ID). If you didn't receive this option whilst setting up your iPhone then skip and once you are in the springboard you can go into settings and do so via the iCloud settings panel.